# Facebook SDK iOS FriendPicker and PlacePicker not existent in SDK 4.x

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Been searching online through StackOverflow and through Facebook SDK Developer docs, can't seem to find where/if the current iOS SDK for Facebook (4.x) has the FBFriendPicker or FBPlacePicker as seen in these links:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.5/protocol/FBFriendPickerDelegate
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.8/protocol/FBPlacePickerDelegate/

Does the FriendPicker and PlacePicker not exist in the iOS SDK 4.x? Trying to implement it for one of my iOS apps.

Comment: Please search at github https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk

Answer (score 1):

No, It doesn't exists...

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/upgrading-4.x

> FBViewController and related picker classes such as FBCacheDescriptor
>   have been removed. If you want to display Graph API results in a table
>   view, you can do it manually. Take a look at the Scrumptious or
>   RPSSample for ideas to get started.